# checking to see if there is a way to chain a function after querySelector even though it might be empty?

Tags: javascript

Just wanted to see if there's a cleaner way of doing the following with querySelector and without the use of jQuery.

```
document.querySelector('#cancel-message').addEventListener('click', () => $("#accession_message").modal("hide"));
```

The above will raise an 'undefined' error on pages where the element does not exist and I know the problem can be avoided using jQuery or just doing the following:

```
x = document.querySelector('#cancel-message');
 if(x) {
   x.addEventListener('click', () => $("#accession_message").modal("hide")); 
 }
```

i want to see if it can be done using vanilla javascript and i'm wondering if there's a javascript method/function that i can chain to it after querySelector and before 'addEventListener' so that it will only execute the next chained function if the element exists and prevents the 'undefined' error being triggered. is there such a thing?? e.g.

```
document.querySelector('#cancel-message'). javacriptFunction() .addEventListener('click', () => $("#accession_message").modal("hide"));
```

Comment: If you can not chain addEventListener at this point because you got no object to call that method on – then you can of course not call any _other_ method on it either. `null` is `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) is implemented (or you use Babel to transpile your code with [this plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining)), you can use `?.`:

```
document.querySelector('#cancel-message')?.addEventListener('click', () => $("#accession_message").modal("hide")); 
//                                       ^^
```

This way, if `querySelector` evaluates to `null`, the whole expression will evaluate to `undefined`, and `addEventListener` will not be called.

Outside of that, there's no way to avoid the `if` check in vanilla Javascript.

(But don't be afraid of using an explicit `if` - longer, readable code is arguably better than shorter, golfed code, all else equal)